# Zero out files in folder(s) that have space in file name

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to zero out (truncate) all the files in a folder or subtree
that match a wildcard. Another post recommended
using the `find … -exec` method over `for variable in wildcard`,
which received high reviews. When I tried the `find … -exec` method, however,
I couldn't get it to work for files with spaces in their names.

Two methods attempted:

`for` method (works):

```
for x in *.wav; do echo -n "" > "$x"; done
```

`find` method (need help):

```
find . -type f -iname \*.wav -exec > "{}" \;
```

which yields

```
find: invalid argument `;' to `-exec'
```

and creates a file called `{}` of zero bytes.

Note that replacing `> "{}"` with `echo {}` prints the list of files in the folder, so the syntax is close.  Just need to figure out how to mitigate the error with spaced file names.

Comment: As noted in my comment below, `-exec > {}` doesn't work, ***ever***, period. This has nothing to do with spaces in filenames.

Comment: I would be very careful about testing these solutions... Sounds sketchy!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `find` command is that it expects `-exec` to handle a `>`,
but `find … -exec` handles only simple commands.  Only the shell knows how to interpret `>`. 
(OK, there may be one or two other programs that can do so, but `find` is not one of them.)

If you want something close to what you’ve got, use

```
find . -type f -iname "*.wav" -exec sh -c '> "$1"' - {} \;
```

in which you tell `find` to execute a shell,
and you use `-c` to tell the shell to execute a **c**ommand
that consists of `>` followed by the filename. 
I would recommend that you do something simpler:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.wav" -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll use the cp /dev/null method, elsewhere I had saw a comment that the 'find' method was superior to the 'for' method.  I also recently saw someone mention the use of a truncate tool, which might also be good.  I assume no one makes any of these tools recursive since they're consider risky.  Although I consider rm -rf to be as risky.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious where you're reading this advice. As discussed in [Looping through files with spaces in the names](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496/80216) (on our Unix&Linux site), `for x in \`find . -name "*.wav"\`` is the sort of thing you really need to avoid. `for x in *.wav` isn't so bad.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to quote the `{}` construct in `find -exec`:

```
find . -type f -name '* *' -exec ls {} \;
```

You cannot use `>` in `find -exec`, it just wants a command and parameters. Create a script to call from `find -exec` if you need it.

Comment: -exec > {} works fine for files without spaces, only receive error on files which contain spaces.  What syntax per your example would you use to zero-out the found files?  I'm guessing -exec rm {}; touch {} \; is the only option?

Comment: @TheHairyOne: For me, `-exec > {}` returns ``find: invalid argument `;' to -exec'`` and creates an empty file `{}`. The option is to create a script `truncate.sh` which does what you want to `"$1"` and then call it from `-exec`.

Comment: @TheHairyOne: I concur: `-exec > {}` doesn't work, ***ever***, period. This has nothing to do with spaces in filenames.